# C++のクラスについての質問です。

Tags: c++

①friend bool operator <=, >=, ==のところなのですが.
　①(<=).もしs1の中にs2の数字が全てあるならReturn True.
　②(>=).もしs2のなかにs1の数字が全てあるなら Return true.     
　③(==)もしs1とs2の中の数字が一緒なら　Return true   にしたいのですがうまくいきません。

②void remove アレイから特定の数字を抜く（この場合はs4の中から99を抜く）と
void clear アレイの数字を全て消す（s1の中の全ての数字）
というファンクションを作りたいのですが全くうまくいきません。（そもそもvoidで正しいのでしょうか…？）

エラーが出るのは②だけです。分かる方がいたら教えてもらえると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MySet
{
public:
    MySet();
    friend bool operator ^ (int element, const MySet &s);
    friend MySet operator + (MySet s, int element);       
    friend MySet operator + (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const MySet &s);
    friend MySet operator * (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2);
    friend MySet operator - (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2);
    friend bool operator <= (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2); // subset
    friend bool operator >= (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2); //supterset
    friend bool operator == (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s4);
    void remove(int element, const MySet &s);
    void clear(const MySet &s);
    int size() const;
private:
    int numbers[100];
    int count; //have to be size?
};

int main()
{
      MySet s1;
      cout << "s1: " << s1 << endl; //should print {}
      if (s1.size() == 0) {
            cout << "Set 1 is empty" << endl;
      }
      s1 = s1 + 10; //add an element to s1
      s1 = s1 + 10;
      s1 = s1 + 20;
      cout << "S1: " << s1 << endl;//should print {10, 20}
      if (10 ^ s1) //test membership
      {
            cout << "10 is an element of S1: " << s1 << endl;
      }  
      MySet s2;
      //add elements to s2
      s2 = s2 + 10;
      s2 = s2 + 40;
      s2 = s2 + 50;
      s2 = s2 + 20;
      cout << "S2: " << s2 << endl;
      //S3 is the union of s1 and s2
      MySet s3 = s1 + s2;
      cout << "S3 (S1 + S2): " << s3 << endl;
      //s3 is the intersection of s1 and s2
      s3 = s1 * s2;
      cout << "S3 (S1 * S2): " << s3 << endl;
      //s3 is the differenct of s1 and s2
      s3 = s1 - s2;
      cout << "S3 (S1 - S2): " << s3 << endl;
      //test the subset operation
      if (s1 <= s2)
      {
            cout << "S1 is a subset of S2" << endl;
      }
      //test the superset operation
      if (s2 >= s1)
      {
            cout << "S2 is a superset of s1" << endl;
      }
      MySet s4;
      s4 = s4 + 20;
      s4 = s4 + 10;
      cout << "S4: " << s4 << endl;
      //test equality
      if (s1 == s4)
      {
            cout << "S1 equals S4" << endl;
      }
      s4 = s4 + 99;
      s4 = s4 + 100;
      cout << "S4: " << s4 << endl;
      s4.remove(99);
      cout << "S4 after removing 99: " << s4 << endl;
      s1.clear();
      cout << "After clearing s1: " << s1 << endl; //should print {}
      return 0; //or EXIT_SUCCESS
}

MySet::MySet()
{
    count = 0 ;
}

bool operator ^ (int element, const MySet &s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
    {
        if(element == s.numbers[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

MySet operator + (MySet s, int element)
{
    if(!(element ^ s))    //if one is T and other is F = T, both T or F = F 
    {
        s.numbers[s.count] = element;
        s.count++;
    }
    return s;
}

MySet operator + (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2)
{
    MySet s3;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.count; ++i)
    {
        s3 = s3 + s1.numbers[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s2.count; ++i)
    {
        s3 = s3 + s2.numbers[i];
    }
    return s3;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const MySet &s)
{
    out << "{";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
    {
        out << s.numbers[i];
        if(!(i == (s.count - 1)))
        {
            out << ", ";
        }
    }
    out << "}";
    return out;
}

MySet operator * (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2)
{
    MySet s3;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.count; ++i)
    {
        if(s1.numbers[i] ^ s2)
        {
            s3 = s3 + s1.numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return s3;
}

MySet operator - (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2)
{
    MySet s3;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.count; ++i)
    {
        if(!(s1.numbers[i] ^ s2))
        {
            s3 = s3 + s1.numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return s3;
}

bool operator <= (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2)  // subset
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.count; ++i)
    {
        if(!(s1.numbers[i] ^ s2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool operator >= (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s2) //supterset
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s2.count; ++i)
    {
        if(!(s2.numbers[i] ^ s1))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool operator == (const MySet &s1, const MySet &s4)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.count; ++i)
    {
        if(!(s1.numbers[i] ^ s4))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s4.count; ++i)
    {
        if(!(s4.numbers[i] ^ s1))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int MySet::size() const
{
    return count;
}

void MySet::remove(int element, const MySet &s)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < s.count; ++i)
        {
            if(s.numbers[i] == element)
            {
                s.numbers[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
}

void MySet::clear(const MySet &s)
{
    s.clear();
}
```

Comment: `<=`、`>=`、`==`についてですが、うまく動作しているように見えます。期待している結果と実際の結果を追記していただけますか。

Comment: s1: {}
Set 1 is empty
S1: {10, 20}
10 is an element of S1: {10, 20}
S2: {10, 40, 50, 20}
S3 (S1 + S2): {10, 20, 40, 50}
S3 (S1 * S2): {10, 20}
S3 (S1 - S2): {}
S1 is a subset of S2
S2 is a superset of s1
S4: {20, 10}
S1 equals S4
S4: {20, 10, 99, 100}

Comment: s1: {}
Set 1 is empty
S1: {10, 20}
10 is an element of S1: {10, 20}
S2: {10, 40, 50, 20}
S3 (S1 + S2): {10, 20, 40, 50}
S3 (S1 * S2): {10, 20}
S3 (S1 - S2): {}
S1 is a subset of S2
S4: {20, 10}
S1 equals S4
S4: {20, 10, 99, 100}

Comment: すみません。このサイトを使い始めてせいで誤送信してしまいました。

Comment: S1: {10, 20}そして、S2: {10, 40, 50, 20}なのでs１はs２のSubsetですがs２はs１のSupersetにならないという風にしたいのですが最初に送った結果では両方ともReturn Trueになっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`<=`, `>=`について**

`main`関数の中で、`<=`のテストは

`if (s1 <= s2)`

としていますが、`>=`のテストは

`if (s2 >= s1)`

と、符号だけでなく`s1`と`s2`も入れ替わっています。ちゃんと実装できていれば、同じ結果になるはずで、実際そうなっているので問題はありません。

---

**`remove`について**
`main`関数で呼び出しているように
`s.remove(99)`
のように使いたいのなら、メンバー関数を使うので、`s`は暗黙的に関数に渡されます。したがって

```
class MySet
{
public:
    // 省略
    void remove(int element);
    // 省略
};
```

でOKです。詳しくはC++の参考書を見てください。

それから、今のアルゴリズムだと
`count = 3; numbers = [10, 20, 90, ....]`
の時に20を削除すると
`count = 3; numbers = [10, 0, 90, ....]`
となり正常に動作しません。削除した20のあとの数を前に一つずつずらして、`count`を一つ減らす必要があります。